# Effect of Long Pressure Cooking on Essential Nutrients

Tags: nutrition, micronutrients, cooking

My dietary staple is currently a soup made from meat, bone, and assorted vegetables pressure cooked for two hours at 15 psi (at the boiling point of about 250° F). I consume it in its entirety, including the bones which become soft and edible. Since this is my primary source of nutrients, I am concerned that the persistent use of pressure cooking may lead to imbalance.

I have found many studies that suggest that certain vitamins (such as vitamin C) are retained very well by pressure cooking, but all these studies use very short cooking times -- minutes, not hours.

I can easily estimate the nutrients going into the pressure cooker, but I'm having a hard time estimating the nutrients coming out. **Does anyone have information of the effect of pressure cooking for long times (hours) on the nutrient content of food?**

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE! Please feel invited to take the [tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and to read the [help documents](https://health.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: I think this question would be more appropriate in the cooking exchange and would get better answers there.

Comment: The cooking exchange is "for professional and amateur cooks and chefs," while the health exchange is "for medical specialists, students, dietitians, and anyone with health-related questions." Why would a chef be more knowledgeable about micronutrient loss than a dietitian?

Comment: Because we don’t have dietitians on the site an we don’t deal with the chemical reactions fold undergoes while cooking. This is basically what @CareyGregory said. This Q would be on topic if you ask as what chemical X does to one‘s body.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is asking about the chemical decomposition and alteration of nutrients during a special cooking technique, which is not directly related to Health.SE and does not meat the scope.

Comment: "What topics can I ask about here? If your question is about... Environmental or nutritional factors that affect health ... then this is the right place to ask." The tour says dietitians. The on-topic description describes questions exactly like this. Perhaps you'd rather I rephrased: "What is the effect of this cooking method on health?" Just because I added more details to narrow the scope by focusing on micronutrients does not make it off-topic.

Comment: Well, this question is definitely off-topic for the cooking exchange. If not here, then where should I post it?

Comment: Basically, if the temperature is high for a long time, wouldn't all thermolabile substances be more or less destroyed? I think the question might be borderline in scope, but we don't seem to have the capacity to answer it at the moment. If your research yields a question on specific conditions (time, pressure, temperature) and specific nutrient(s) we might give it a try (through extensive literature research), but so might chemistry SE (you might want to check before posting though).